# jquery display qr code

Tags: javascript, jquery, qr-code

qr code append very time i click on modal.
when I pop up modal, I content to display with qr code

I used `jquery.qrcode-0.11.0.js`

and this is my code when modal show

`$('.div_qr_print').qrcode({"render": "image","size": 87,"text": 'mytext'});`

at first click, qr generate correct but when I click second or third time, qr code will append more and more like this 
[image]

**How to replace value `text` **not append more**

Comment: Before rendering QR code in DIV, you should clear its contents first then render QR code.

Comment: Oh, good! I really stupid.

Answer (score 0):

I'd wipe the HTML and then display the new QR code.  For the example, I used a  click event to update the text value.  I used `data` to support more than one QR code.

```js
$('.div_qr_print')
  .data("qr",{
    "render": "image",
    "size": 87,
    "text":'mytext'
  })
  .qrcode($('.div_qr_print').data("qr"))
  .click(function () {
    $(this).data("qr").text = "new text";
    $(this)
      .html("")
      .qrcode($(this).data("qr"));
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.qrcode/1.0/jquery.qrcode.min.js"></script>

<div class="div_qr_print"></div>
```